# DFP mediated Admob house ad keeps promoting ads after target app has been installed

Tags: android, admob, double-click, google-dfp, double-click-advertising

I am trying to use DFP mediated admob house ads to promote my android apps. However I met an issue.

In admob side, I got app A and app B registered in admob account, and set a house campaign: app A will promote B.

In DFP side, I set line items for the A and B to mediate admob units. and I have tested that A can promote B via device successfully.

But the problem is, after released the two apps in Google Playstore. I download and open app A, then click house ad to install and run app B. then I go back to app A, the app B's ad will keep popping out.

In admob official document, they say this for house ads:

> AdMob will only promote your app to users who haven't already
>   installed it themselves.

So in ideal situation, app A should stop promoting app B after user has installed B. While it's not what I see in my test.

Anyone met this issue? Is it possible caused by DFP mediation?

Comment: That's an interesting setup. Do you mind reposting this in our SDK support forum (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-admob-ads-sdk)? It's easier to have a running conversation there, and it's possible to privately send your ad unit IDs to the support team so they can try to replicate the issue.

Comment: I have already posted my issue there, but they said this is not a SDK issue,  and asked me to contact admob product team. then I send mails to product team as the forum said, and they asked me to send mail to product team again...I'm really confused. do you know anyone from admob product team who I can contact directly?